# How to add information in ASP.NET Exception Stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, elmah

I want to put some extra info on how program works, if theres an exception, then I like these extra info be wrote in the exception report, the normal whole lot info that ELMAH recorded.

And if theres no exception, then I do not need the info, just let it go. So I do not think write everything in log is a good idea for me.

Please advice how can I write extra info that will recorded with the exception. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own exception class

```
public class YourCustomException : Exception
{
    public YourCustomException(Exception inner, string message)
    : base(inner, message)
    {
    }

}
```

... and add additional information to the Message.

```
try
{
   // ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new YourCustomException(ex, "More information");
}
```